# Get object properties from a generic object in java

Tags: java, object, generics, properties

I have a method to get properties from a generic object in c# below. How can I get the same in java?

```
public string GetProperty<T>(T obj)
        {
            var s = string.Empty;
            var t = obj.GetType();
            foreach (var pi in t.GetProperties()) 
                s += "  " + pi.Name + ":" + pi.GetValue(obj, null);
            return s;
        }
```

Suppose I have a class Emp as below

```
public class Emp {
    int Id;
    String Msisdn;
    
    
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getMsisdn() {
        return Msisdn;
    }
    public void setMsisdn(String msisdn) {
        Msisdn = msisdn;
    }
    
}
```

I want to call a method like below

```
public Emp data = new Emp();
emp.setId(1);
emp.SetMsisdn("1404850126");

String s = ConvertString(data);
```

It will Return

> Id:1 Msisdn:1404850126

Answer (score 0):

Use class `PropertyUtils` from [Apache Commons BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Emp emp = new Emp();
  emp.setId(1);
  emp.setMsisdn("msisdnvalue");

  try {
    String msisdn = (String) PropertyUtils.getProperty(emp, "msisdn");
    System.out.println(String.format("msisdn: %s", msisdn));
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```